# Correlated noise in Kalman filter

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, control-theory, signal-processing, kalman-filter

Assume a standard state-space setting:
\begin{align}
x_{t+1} &= Ax_t + w_t\\
y_t &= Cx_t+v_t,
\end{align}
where the noise sequences are i.i.d. Gaussian with $w_i\sim N(0,W)$ and $v_i\sim N(0,V)$.

I am interested in the pre- and post- error covariance matrices recursions when there is a correlation $\mathbb{E}[w_tv_t^\top]= S$.

Specifically, using the notation
\begin{align}
\Sigma_{t|t} &= \mathbf{cov}(x_{t}|y^t)\\
\Sigma_{t+1|t} &= \mathbf{cov}(x_{t+1}|y^t),
\end{align}
how does the standard propagations:
\begin{align}
\Sigma_{t|t}&= \Sigma_{t|t-1} - \Sigma_{t|t-1} C^\top (C\Sigma_{t|t-1}C^\top+V)^{-1}C \Sigma_{t|t-1}\\
\Sigma_{t+1|t} &= A\Sigma_{t|t}A^\top+W
\end{align}
change. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use your notation, and also define the conditional mean $\hat x_{t|s} = \mathbf{E}(x_t \mid y^{s})$.

The way you wrote the KF updates in your question have them split in two steps, the "measurement update" $(t|t-1) \to (t|t)$ and the "time update" $(t|t) \to (t+1|t)$.

In general, you can just combine the two updates into a single update $(t|t-1) \to (t+1|t)$. Here is what you get for the case $S\neq 0$ when you do that; these are the standard KF update equations.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Sigma_{t+1|t} &= \left(A \Sigma_{t|t-1} A^\top + W\right) - \left( A \Sigma_{t|t-1} C^\top + S \right) \left( C \Sigma_{t|t-1} C^\top + V \right)^{-1} \left( C \Sigma_{t|t-1}A^\top + S^\top\right) \\
L_t &= \left( A \Sigma_{t|t-1} C^\top + S \right) \left( C \Sigma_{t|t-1} C^\top + V \right)^{-1} \\
\hat x_{t+1|t} &= A \hat x_{t|t-1} + L_t (y_t - C\hat x_{t|t-1})
\end{aligned}
$$

If you want to look at the measurement and time updates separately, that's also possible. The measurement update when $S\neq 0$ is the same as in the case $S=0$. For completeness sake, here is the measurement update:

\begin{align}
\hat x_{t|t} &= \hat x_{t|t-1} + \Sigma_{t|t-1} C^\top (C\Sigma_{t|t-1}C^\top +V)^{-1}(y_t - C \hat x_{t|t-1})\\
\Sigma_{t|t} &= \Sigma_{t|t-1} - \Sigma_{t|t-1} C^\top (C\Sigma_{t|t-1}C^\top+V)^{-1}C \Sigma_{t|t-1}
\end{align}

The time update is different when $S\neq 0$. Actually, you can't write $(t+1|t)$ neatly in terms of just $(t|t)$. I'll try to give some insight. When $S=0$, you can take the state update equation $x_{t+1} = Ax_t + w_t$ and take conditional expectations given $(y_0,\dots,y_t)$ and directly obtain $\hat x_{t+1|t} = A \hat x_{t|t}$ and $\Sigma_{t+1|t} = A\Sigma_{t|t}A^\top + W$. This works because $x_t$ and $w_t$ are independent. But when $S\neq 0$, although $x_t$ and $w_t$ are still independent by assumption, they become correlated when you condition given $(y_0,\dots,y_t)$, since $y_t$ depends on $x_t$ and $v_t$ (which is correlated with $w_t$), i.e. $y_t$ is correlated with both $x_t$ and $w_t$. Therefore, your terms involving $(w_t|y^t)$ will need to be expressed in terms of $(w_t|y^{t-1})$, which is simply $w_t$, but this introduces dependency on $(x_t|y^{t-1})$, which we were trying to avoid in the first place. Working through this, you get:

\begin{align}
\hat x_{t+1|t} &= A\hat x_{t|t} + S (C\Sigma_{t|t-1}C^\top +V)^{-1}(y_t - C \hat x_{t|t-1})\\
\Sigma_{t+1|t} &= A\Sigma_{t|t}A^\top + W - \left( A \Sigma_{t|t-1} C^\top + S \right) \left( C \Sigma_{t|t-1} C^\top + V \right)^{-1} \left( C \Sigma_{t|t-1}A^\top + S^\top\right)\\
&\hspace{1cm}+A\Sigma_{t|t-1} C^\top (C\Sigma_{t|t-1}C^\top+V)^{-1}C \Sigma_{t|t-1}A^\top
\end{align}

Note that combining the measurement and time updates recovers the standard KF update equations at the top of the post.

Comment: I edited my answer to address the relation between prediction and estimation error. The short version is that when $S \neq 0$, one of the updates stays the same but the other one changes. The one that changes does so in a way that forces you to combine both updates into a single update.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I could derive the missing equation using the innovations approach: Let $e_t:= y_t - C\hat{x}_{t|t-1}$, then the prediction step (time update in your answer) is: \begin{align} \hat{x}_{t+1|t}= A\hat{x}_{t|t} + \hat{w}_{t|t} \end{align} with $\hat{w}_{t|t}= S (C^T\Sigma_{t|t-1}C+V)^{-1}e_t$.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. And you can also verify that if you combine the original measurement update with the time updates in your comment, you obtain the standard KF equations at the top of my post.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to verify now. 1. Perhaps you would like to embed this step in your answer so that people will have access to both steps? 2. This step is of particular interest to me since it means that the "measurement quality" effects the prediction step as well. In standard KF, the measurement step is the only effected by the measurement via the well-known information filter formula $\Sigma_{t|t}^{-1} = \Sigma_{t|t-1}^{-1} + C V^{-1}C^\top$. Perhaps my next challenge is to understand if there is such a nice formula for the prediction step when $S\neq 0$.Will be happy for any input.

Comment: The covariance had a major typo, it should be:
\begin{align}
\Sigma_{t+1|t}= A\Sigma_{t|t}A^T + W - S(C\Sigma_{t|t-1}C^T + V)^{-1} S^T - A \Sigma_{t|t}C^T (C\Sigma_{t|t-1}C^T + V)^{-1}S^T -  S (C\Sigma_{t|t-1}C^T + V)^{-1}  C \Sigma_{t|t} A^T
\end{align}

Comment: I think that's still incorrect. The $A\Sigma_{t|t} C^T$ terms should be $A\Sigma_{t|t-1}C^T$ instead. Basically the only thing on the right-hand side that's $(t|t)$ is the first term, $A\Sigma_{t|t}A^T$.

Comment: I made one last update to my answer. At this point, I think it's about as complete as it can get. Note that the information filter formula $\Sigma_{t|t}^{-1}=\Sigma_{t|t-1}^{-1} +C^\top V^{-1} C$ still holds in the case where $S\neq 0$. It's just the time update $\Sigma_{t+1|t}=A\Sigma_{t|t}A^\top + W$ that changes and has a bunch of extra stuff added on to it, which unfortunately, doesn't appear to simplify.